# How to filter the results for categories in algolia?

Tags: ios, swift, algolia

Here I am using the algolia to display the categories selected data to pass and load data in list page according to it and here I passed the selected data to the list page but here unable to load the data required for selected category and got crashed in `index.search` a line can anyone help me how to resolve this?

Here is my selected facet filters array data which I was passing from my categories page

> ["[categories.level0:Men]", "[categories.level1:Men///Tops]"]
>   [categories.level2:Men///Tops///Tees]

and below is my facets array data

```
["categories.level0", "categories.level1", "categories.level2", "gometoo_seller", "style_bottom", "climate", "sleeve", "gender", "category_gear", "eco_collection", "pattern", "collar", "style_bags", "style_general", "is_trending", "erin_recommends", "format", "performance_fabric", "strap_bags", "features_bags", "activity", "material", "categories", "color", "is_new", "size", "price", "manufacturer", "price.BHD.default", "price.EGP.default", "price.EUR.default", "price.KWD.default", "price.OMR.default", "price.SAR.default", "price.USD.default", "price.AED.default"]
```

here is my image for algolia data

[image]

here is my algolia back end data

```
index.search("", {
 "hitsPerPage": "10",
 "page": "0",
 "analytics": "false",
 "attributesToRetrieve": "*",
 "facets": "[\"categories.level0\",\"categories.level1\",\"categories.level2\",\"activity\",\"category_gear\",\"climate\",\"color\",\"eco_collection\",\"erin_recommends\",\"features_bags\",\"format\",\"gender\",\"gometoo_seller\",\"is_new\",\"is_trending\",\"material\",\"pattern\",\"performance_fabric\",\"price.AED.default\",\"price.BHD.default\",\"price.EGP.default\",\"price.EUR.default\",\"price.KWD.default\",\"price.OMR.default\",\"price.SAR.default\",\"price.USD.default\",\"size\",\"strap_bags\",\"style_bags\",\"style_bottom\",\"style_general\"]",
 "facetFilters": "[[\"categories.level2:Men /// Tops /// Tees\"],[\"categories.level1:Men /// Tops\"],[\"categories.level0:Men\"]]"
});
```

and the code for this is

```
if (self.appId != nil && self.apiKEY != nil && self.Indices != nil) {
            InstantSearch.shared.configure(appID: "\(self.appId!)", apiKey: "\(self.apiKEY!)", index: "\(self.Indices!)en_products")
            InstantSearch.shared.params.attributesToRetrieve = ["*"]
            InstantSearch.shared.registerAllWidgets(in: self.view)
            let query = Query()
            query.facets = facetsArray
            query.facetFilters = categoriesArray
            index.search(query, completionHandler: { (res, error) in
                self.listCollectionView.reloadData()
            })
            hitsCollectionViews = [self.listCollectionView]
            ActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()  
        }
```

Comment: What is the crash ?

Comment: Unexpectedly found nil while wrapping optional value @RobertD.Mogos

Comment: Could you please paste the entire crash ?

Comment: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
2018-02-26 14:24:51.662339+0530 Gometoo[7959:277926] Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value this was the crash in the log

Comment: I meant the entire stack trace

Comment: new to swift 3 just let me know how to check stack trace @RobertD.Mogos

Comment: implementing algolia for the first time please help me @RobertD.Mogos

Comment: in stack trace it shows The operation couldn’t be completed. (mydomain error 123.) @RobertD.Mogos

Comment: is this the stack trace which u asked https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErjVS.png ? @RobertD.Mogos

Comment: Can you check if `index` is *nil* or `listCollectionView` is nil ?

Comment: in index only it got nil  @RobertD.Mogos

Comment: So that's your problem. You need to initialise index first, before using it

Comment: actually index which I initialized was a class of `AlgoliaSearch-client`

Comment: Can you paste the method where you are initialising it ?

Comment: I was initialising before view did load like shown here var index : Index!

Comment: That's not initialising that's declaration. But you don't need to use the index. Take a look at this: https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch-ios/blob/master/Readme.md

Comment: And you have a bunch of examples here: https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch-ios-examples

Comment: by seeing above examples I tried instant search by search bar which implemented but unable to implement the filter of data using facets

Comment: The crash is not coming from Algolia, is coming from your code. The index is nil, hence the crash